# Using parent class constructor to reassign value to inherited variables

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance

I have a C++ class B inherited from a class A. I probably miss an important concept of OOP and this certainly quite trivial, but I do not understand how I can, after the instantiation of B, use the constructor of A inside B to reassign new values *only* to the local variables inherited from A:

*Class A*

```
class A{
    public:
        A(int a, int b){
            m_foo = a;
            m_bar = b;
            }
    protected:
        int m_foo;
        int m_bar;
};
```

*Class B*

```
class B : public A{
    public:
        B(int a, int b, int c):A(a,b),m_loc(c){};
        void resetParent(){
            /* Can I use the constructor of A to change m_foo and 
             * m_bar without explicitly reassigning value? */

            A(10,30); // Obviously, this does not work :)

            std::cout<<m_foo<<"; "<<m_bar<<std::endl; 
            }
    private:
        int m_loc;
};
```

*Main*

```
int main(){
    B b(0,1,3);
    b.resetParent();
    return 1;
    }
```

In this specific example, I would like to call `b.resetParent()` which should call `A::A()` to change the values of `m_foo` and `m_bar` (in `b`) to 10 and 30, respectively. 
I should therefore print "10; 30" rather than "0; 1".

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use constructor to change an object, only to construct it. To change an already constructed object you need to use it's `public` and `protected` (in case of a derived `class`) members. In your example `A` needs to implement a `reset()` member function that can be later used to reset it's state.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot call the base class constructor to reset the values.  However, the values you want to reset are declared as `protected` which means `B` has direct access to them:

```
void resetParent()
{
    m_foo = 10;
    m_bar = 30;

    std::cout << m_foo << "; " << m_bar << std::endl; 
}
```

**If** `A` has an `=` assignment operator defined, you could alternatively declare a temp `A` instance and assign it to the base class:

```
void resetParent()
{
    *this = A(10, 30);
    // or:
    // A::operator=(A(10, 30));

    std::cout << m_foo << "; " << m_bar << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in this example, my point was not to touch to m_foo and m_bar directly. Your second point is however very interesting to me. I was wondering, if I do `this* = A(10,30)`; what happens to `m_loc`. Intuitively, I would imagine it does not exist any more.

Comment: Nothing happens to `m_loc`. That would require calling `B::operator=()` with a `B` instance, but that is not what the code is doing. It is calling `A::operator=()` with an `A` instance, so only `A` members would be affecte (in theory anyway, since I have never used base class assignment operators outside of derived class assignment operators like this).